# How to get months duration between two dates in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select  datediff (curdate(), hire_date )  as diff
from emp
order by hire_date asc;
```

But, this does not give the output in months, how to get it in months?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

try something like: `SELECT DATEDIFF(month, curdate(), hire_date) AS diff`

Answer (score 0):

You can you Timestamp in MySQL

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,curdate(),hire_date);
```

For SQL Server

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, curdate(), hire_date) AS DateDiff;
```